# Kafka’s literature

Tags: grammar

*The »East« is a persistent theme in the research on **Kafka’s literature**, but this East is confined to Europe. There are innumerable studies devoted to the tensions between the Jews of central and western Europe, reflecting also the contrast between the western use of the German language and the eastern use of »jargon« (i.e. Yiddish).*

Given the context, I think that "Kafka‘s literature" means literature (books, studies, articles…) dealing with Kafka. Do you think that the apostrophe in "Kafka" is necessary? In my opinion, "Kafka‘s literature" means something like literature that Kafka liked or had in his library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Kafka's literature" refers to literature written by Kafka. The apostrophe means that it is his literature.

"Kafka literature" doesn't mean anything. But there is "literature about Kafka," which describes his work and life.